# Is there a way to filter / search for content in a HTMLEditorKit?

Tags: java, swing, search, filter

I have a normal HTMLEditorKit() object:

```
        historyKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        historyDoc = new HTMLDocument();
        history = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
        JScrollPane historyScrollPane = new JScrollPane(history);
        historyPanel.add(historyScrollPane, "cell 0 0 1 2,grow");
        history.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null,
                null, null));
```

I use it as some sort of "log", so it gets updated according to this object:

```
public class Logger {

    public static ArrayList<String[]> log = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public static void update(String s) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy | HH:mm:ss");
        String historyText = "<b>" + sdf.format(new Date()) + "</b>: " + s;
        String[] sArray = { sdf.format(new Date()), s };
        log.add(sArray);
        append(historyText);
    }

    public static void append(String s) {
        MainFrame.history.setEditorKit(MainFrame.historyKit);
        MainFrame.history.setDocument(MainFrame.historyDoc);
        try {
            MainFrame.historyKit.insertHTML(MainFrame.historyDoc,
                    MainFrame.historyDoc.getLength(), s, 0, 0, null);
        } catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The thing is, I believe it would more complicated to "traverse" the data structure in order to filter the content according to some JTextField, than it would be to "traverse" the component itself (In that case, the model, I suppose). Is there a well-known way of filtering documents, using a text field as a "search field"?

Comment: Use a JTextPane then you can just search for the text without worrying about HTML tags.

Comment: I'm using the HTML kit so that I can highlight different parts of the text (The date, for example, being bold). All the String in the same font / color is really horrible to read (I know, perhaps I could have being more clever and done some black magick with labels, or even used a highly customized JTable, but anyway). Of course, there's always the option to drop aesthetics in favor of pragmatism.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using the HTML kit so that I can highlight different parts of the text

A `JTextPane` can be used with different fonts, colors etc.

Here is a simple example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextPaneAttributes extends JPanel
{

    public TextPaneAttributes()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText( "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight" );

        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

        //  Define some character and paragraph attribute sets

        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

        SimpleAttributeSet green = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

        SimpleAttributeSet left = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(left, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);

        //  Change attributes on some existing text

        doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 3, keyWord, false);
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(8, 5, green, true);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(20, 1 , center, false);

        //  Add some text with attributes

        try
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nNormal text", null);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nGreen text centered", green);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(doc.getLength(), 1 , center, false);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nKeyword text", keyWord);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(doc.getLength(), 1 , left, false);

            //  Newly typed text at the end of the document will inherit the
            //  "keyword" attributes unless we remove the attributes

            textPane.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength());
            textPane.getInputAttributes().removeAttributes(keyWord);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}

        //  Add text pane to frame

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 250 ) );
        add( scrollPane );

        //  Create a Button panel

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //  Add a Bold button

        JButton bold = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction() );
        buttons.add( bold );

        //  Add Right Alignment button

        JButton right = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.AlignmentAction("Align Right", StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT) );
        buttons.add( right );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextPaneAttributes());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information and example.