# Multiple fonts and styles in JTextComponent

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextcomponent

I am looking for a way to print content in JTextComponent's text with multiple fonts and styles.
For example: first Title with bigger font and then some custom text in different style in one component

Comment: you need to use separate instances to achieve that

Comment: A `JTextPane` makes use of a `StyledDocument`, I sugget having a look at [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) as a primer

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184448/surrounding-jtextpane-with-images/22185053#22185053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JTextPane` for this. You can control font, color, bold, size etc.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information and working examples.

For a another simple example to get you started check out: [Is there a way to filter / search for content in a HTMLEditorKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059544/is-there-a-way-to-filter-search-for-content-in-a-htmleditorkit/43060554#43060554)